# layer selector map: two variables

Tags: carto, cartography

I want to map layer selection as the example of cartodb (http://cartodb.github.io/cartodb.js/examples/layer_selector.html), the difference is that I want to choose a date in the layer selector and it work as a filter and show me one other column data. Anyone have a solution that can help me soon and I apologize for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this toggle map view tutorial from CartoDB is exactly what you want to achieve: http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view.html

In this case, instead of dates they're using another information, but you just have to edit the SQL queries conveniently depending on your case.

Comment: thanks, well this form isn´t the same that I want but these form is more easy. Thank you